# How do I integrate the visual studio SCC plugin with my CMAKE generated solution/project

Tags: visual-studio, cmake, perforce

All I can find on the subject is a forum post on kitware's site stating I need to add a call to `SET_TARGET_PROPERTIES` in my CMakeLists file where I set the `VS_SCCPROJECTNAME`, `VS_SCCLOCALPATH` and `VS_SCCPROVIDER` properties. I tried the following snippet but the plugin still doesn't prompt me on opening the solution and doesn't auto-checkout files I edit. An help would be greatly appreciated!

```
IF (WIN32)
    SET_TARGET_PROPERTIES (${MY_PROJECT_NAME} PROPERTIES
        VS_SCCPROJECTNAME "Perforce Project"
        VS_SCCLOCALPATH ${THE_ROOT_DIRECTORY_OF_MY_PERFORCE_WORKSPACE_ON_MY_DRIVE}
        VS_SCCPROVIDER "MSSCCI:Perforce SCM"
    )
ENDIF (WIN32)
```

As a side note, my context menu in explorer is also not giving me the "check out" option under the perforce menu group. Perhaps the issues are related?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Oops, missed the underscores in the VS_SCC values. It should have read

```
IF (WIN32)
    SET_TARGET_PROPERTIES (${MY_PROJECT_NAME} PROPERTIES
        VS_SCC_PROJECTNAME "Perforce Project"
        VS_SCC_LOCALPATH ${THE_ROOT_DIRECTORY_OF_MY_PERFORCE_WORKSPACE_ON_MY_DRIVE}
        VS_SCC_PROVIDER "MSSCCI:Perforce SCM"
    )
ENDIF (WIN32)
```

I cleaned my cmake directory and regenerated and now it works